# Does StringIO create a file on disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stringio

In the following example:

```
import sqlite3
from io import StringIO

def init_sqlite_db(app):
    # Read database to tempfile
    con = sqlite3.connect(app.config['SQLITE_DATABASE'])
    tempfile = StringIO()
    for line in con.iterdump():
        tempfile.write('%s\n' % line)
    con.close()
    tempfile.seek(0)
```

Does [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) cause a temporary file to be created on disk or is it all done in memory?

Comment: no. it's all in-memory. This is stated quite clearly in the docs, "An in-memory stream for text I/O. "

Comment: Just wanted to double-check because of the naming conventions people like to use with it being therefor misleading.

Comment: I've never seen that convention, so I wouldn't really call it a *convention*. Normally, I just see something like `buffer = StringIO()`